# remove eventhandler on ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to remove the event handler of an ItemTemplate in asp .net. Here is the asp code

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdbAnswer"  GroupName="Group"  AutoPostBack="True" 
        OnCheckedChanged="rdbAnswer_CheckedChanged" />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to remove the checkedchanged event on code behind. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-=` to remove an event handler. You could do that in [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx):

```
protected void gridView1_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButton rdbAnswer = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("rdbAnswer");
        if(YourCondition)
        {
            // Remove event handler
            rdbAnswer.CheckedChanged -= new EventHandler(rdbAnswer_CheckedChanged);
            // maybe you also want to set rdbAnswer.AutoPostBack="false" to prevent the postback
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to register the `RowCreated` event handler:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" OnRowCreated="gridView1_RowCreated" runat="server">
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, the point is there is no "OnCheckedChanged" event when i write rdbAnswer. There is only "CheckedChanged", i dont think that is the same

Comment: @user1292656: Edited my answer. Use `rdbAnswer.CheckedChanged -= ...` instead of `rdbAnswer.OnCheckedChanged -= ...`. The one is the event the other is the event-handler. I just had not the chance to test it.

Comment: So the event is triggered nevertheless? You could also use `rdbAnswer.CheckedChanged -= rdbAnswer_CheckedChanged`, but that's only a shortcut.

Comment: Have you added the `RowCreated` event handler at all? See my edited answer.